# Why when I'm trying with same credential on postman isn't working but when in vanilla html form it works

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5, postman, razorpay

I'm trying to add a hosted checkout for razorpay but I'm facing an issue that when I'm trying to send a request via HTML form it works but when I create the same form via javascript isn't working. it returns Error Code 400 The current HTTP method is not supported
Same happens with Postman request. I'm using laravel 5.8

HTML Form (working) :

```
          <form method="POST" action="https://api.razorpay.com/v1/checkout/embedded">  
            <input type="text" name="key_id" value="rzp_test_UtGYTNBzepZoVA">  
            <input type="text" name="order_id" value="razorpay_order_id">  
            <input type="text" name="name" value="Acme Corp">  
            <input type="text" name="description" value="A Wild Sheep Chase">  
            <input type="text" name="prefill[name]" value="Gaurav Kumar"> 
            <input type="text" name="prefill[contact]" value="9123456780">  
            <input type="text" name="prefill[email]" value="gaurav.kumar@example.com">  
            <input type="text" name="notes[shipping address]" value="L-16, The Business Centre, 61 Wellfield Road, New Delhi - 110001">  
            <input type="hidden" name="callback_url" value="https://example.com/payment-callback">
            <input type="hidden" name="cancel_url" value="https://example.com/payment-cancel">  <button>Submit</button>
        </form>
```

Javascript (Not Working):

```
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    var element1 = document.createElement("input"); 
    var element2 = document.createElement("input");  
    var element3 = document.createElement("input");  
    var element4 = document.createElement("input"); 
    var element5 = document.createElement("input"); 
    var element6 = document.createElement("input"); 
    var element7 = document.createElement("input"); 
    var element8 = document.createElement("input"); 
    var element9 = document.createElement("input"); 
    var element10 = document.createElement("input"); 
    var element11= document.createElement("input"); 
    form.method = "POST";
    form.action = "https://api.razorpay.com/v1/checkout/embedded"; 
    element1.name="key_id";
    element1.setAttribute("type","text");
    element1.setAttribute("value",key_id);
    form.appendChild(element1);  

    element2.name="order_id";
    element2.setAttribute("type","text");
    element2.setAttribute("value",order_id);
    form.appendChild(element2);

    element3.name="name";
    element3.setAttribute("type","text");
    element3.setAttribute("value",name);
    form.appendChild(element3);

    element4.name="description";
    element4.setAttribute("type","text");
    element4.setAttribute("value",description);
    form.appendChild(element4);

    element5.name="prefill[name]";
    element5.setAttribute("type","text");
    element5.setAttribute("value",prefill["name"]);
    form.appendChild(element5);

    element6.name="prefill[contact]";
    element6.setAttribute("type","text");
    element6.setAttribute("value",prefill["contact"]);
    form.appendChild(element6);

    element7.name="prefill[email]";
    element7.setAttribute("type","text");
    element7.setAttribute("value",prefill["email"]);
    form.appendChild(element7);

    element8.name="notes[shipping address]";
    element8.setAttribute("type","text");
    element8.setAttribute("value",notes["shipping address"]);
    form.appendChild(element8);
    // form.appendChild(element8);

    element9.name="callback_url";
    element9.setAttribute("type","text");
    element9.setAttribute("value",callback_url);
    form.appendChild(element9);
    // form.appendChild(element9);

    element10.name="cancel_url";
    element10.setAttribute("type","text");
    element10.setAttribute("value",cancel_url);
    form.appendChild(element10);

    element11.value=document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute("content");
    element11.name="_method";
    element11.setAttribute("type","hidden");
    form.appendChild(element11);

    console.log(form);
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    console.log(form);
    form.submit();
```

Returned error

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BAD_REQUEST_ERROR",
        "description": "The current http method is not supported"
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure there's no javascript adding some parameters before the form is submitted?

Comment: I have tried with postman. it also returns the same response. BTW could you please let me know the possible reason for the same error in detail

Answer (score -1):

Try using the below JS.

You can also locate all params here: https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-gateway/web-integration/standard/#checkout-form

````
   "key":"<YOUR_KEY_ID>",
   // Enter the Key ID generated from the Dashboard 
    "amount":"29935",
   "name":"Acme Corp",
   "description":"A Wild Sheep Chase is the third novel by Japanese author Haruki Murakami",
 "image":"http://example.com/your_logo.png",
   "handler":function (response)   {  
      alert(response.razorpay_payment_id);
   },
   /** 
* You can track the modal lifecycle by * adding the below code in your options 
*/ 
    "modal":{  
      "ondismiss":function()      {  
         console.log(‘Checkout form closed’);
      }
   }
}; 
var rzp1 = new Razorpay(options);```
````

Comment: but I want to implement a checkout form where the submitted form will firstly manipulate and then it would be forwarded to razorpay via javascript.